# Can't change the scale of legend using ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a DF with clusters 1, 2 and 3.

However, when ploting the clusters on a map I have a legend with 1; 1.5; 2; 2.5; 3. like in the pic [CLUSTER SCALE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pw5B.png)

My actual code:

```
map <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("coords1", "coords2" ))                  
    map <- st_set_crs(map, value  = 4326)
    ggplot(map) + geom_sf(aes(color = groups))+ scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

I tried to use the following method but this is not working:

```
scale_shape_discrete(name  ="CLUSTERS",
                          breaks=c("1", "2", "3"),
                          labels=c("Cluster 1", "Cluster 2", "Cluster 3"))
```

Comment: 1. `scale_shape_...` will not work to adjust a color scale. 2. as your cluster variable is categorical a color gradient makes on sense in my opinion. Maybe `geom_sf(aes(color = factor(groups))) + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"), labels=c("Cluster 1", "Cluster 2", "Cluster 3"))` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're not mapping anything to "shape" so `scale_shape_*` won't change anything. `ggplot` doesn't like it when your groups are labeled with numbers and will tell you about how you're trying to map a continuous variable to a discrete scale. I suspect you should do something like the following, although it is hard to know for sure without seeing an example of how your data are laid out.

```r
ggplot(map) +
geom_sf(aes(color = factor(group)) + 
scale_color_manual(
    name = "CLUSTERS", 
    values = c("red", "green", "blue"), 
    labels = c(paste("Cluster", 1:3))
)
```